# how to remove white space under Bootstrap 4 jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with the jumbotron, white space appear under it for some reason i don't know if its because of my code or a mistake that i made some where . i have been at it for two days now .i copy the code for the jumbotron on the bootstrap 4 website.  i could use some help on this . As you can see by the picture white space appear under it.

```css
.container_fluid.one {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:  #43E8E4;
}
.nav-item {
    padding-right:20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.info h1 {
    margin-top: 170px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.info p {
    font-size: 15px;
}
span {
    color: #fffc00;
}
 span .gold{
    color: #fffc00;
}
.info p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.white {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fffc00;
}
.leader {
    margin-top: 110px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 316px;
}
.down {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.container_fluid.two {
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color:  #43E8E4;
}
.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_fluid one">
  <!--Navbar -->
  <nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark orange lighten-1">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class='bx bxl-stripe bx-md' style="color:#fffc00;"></i></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-555"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-555" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-555">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">
      <span class="gold">Home</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <!--/.Navbar -->
   <section data-aos="zoom-in"data-aos-duration="1900">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 text-white info">
      <h1>I'll go above and beyond for <span>you.</span></h1>
      <p>The world's best.</p>
      <p><span>I am good at what i do.</span></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info white">Learn More</button>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
       <img class="img-fluid leader" src="/images/undraw_site_stats_l57q.svg" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center down">
    <i class='bx bx-down-arrow bx-md bx-fade-down' style="color:#fffc00;"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
   <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
   <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="container_fluid two">
```

[image]

Comment: There may be some margin on elements inside, possibly h1,did you inspect the elements?

Comment: [Hobbs Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14672605/hobbs-pixel) said in an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64922231/12695027) to use `.jumbotron {padding-bottom:1px;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include these lines of code in your CSS file

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because of:

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

So if you want to remove that, simply give a class to your div e.g.: `jumbotron-override` and add this code to css:

```
.jumbotron-override {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The result can be seen on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nabtron/1kesqj8f/4/ (full page: https://fiddle.jshell.net/nabtron/1kesqj8f/4/show/ )

I hope it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to override your code by commenting margin-bottom: 2rem; then white space disappear

```
.jumbotron {
    /* padding: 2rem 1rem; */
    /*margin-bottom: 2rem; */
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border-radius: .3rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to put `!important` after `margin: 0px` to make it work

```
.jumbotron {
margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```